# Apache RewriteRule htaccess security

Tags: apache, htaccess

If I configure an `.htaccess` file like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /view.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Which transforms:

```
original URL   http://www.example.com/view.php?key=123
rewritten URL  http://www.example.com/123
```

Is there any way for an attacker to find the real PHP file (here `view.php`) and directly access it (in the URL bar)?
Considering URL-bruteforce is not an option, nor `.htaccess` reading.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways; php could have display_errors on or you could have HTML source or links that reveal the file location.

URL is a little trickier, but using something like ///view.php might do the job.